# How to set up a simple Backbone/Marionette project and their dependencies using require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I've been reading a lot on this, and even bought a book specifically on setting up marionette apps with require.js, and followed [this](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs) little how-to on github which seemed pretty straightforward...  However for some reason I can't seem to get something as simple as starting an empty Marionette project to work!

My project is structured like so:

- Root Directory

  - models
  - views
  - libs

    - babysitter.js
    - backbone.js
    - jquery.js
    - marionette.js
    - require.js
    - text.js
    - tpl.js
    - underscore.js
    - wreqr.js
  - collections
  - templates
  - index.html
  - main.js

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script data-main="main" src="libs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths:{
    jquery:"libs/jquery",
    underscore: "libs/underscore",
    backbone: "libs/backbone",
    text: "libs/text",
    tpl: "libs/tpl",
    marionette: 'libs/marionette',
    'backbone.wreqr' : 'libs/wreqr',
    'backbone.babysitter' : 'libs/babysitter'
    },
    shim:{
    underscore:{
        exports: "_"
    },
    backbone:{
        deps: ['underscore','jquery'],
        exports:'Backbone'
    }
    }
});

require(['marionette'],function(Marionette){


var Application = new Marionette.Application();

Application.on("initialize:after", function(){
    alert("Application has started!");
});

    Application.start();
});
```

I downloaded the AMD / RequireJS version of Marionette.js from their [site](http://marionettejs.com)

Upon opening up index.html in a browser, I see an error in the console "Reference Error: Backbone is not defined" (on marionette.js line 20)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I looked at the AMD / RequireJS version of Marionette.js from their site, and noticed in the comments at the top, that two libraries are already included in the source: wreqr and babysitter. You don't need to include those in your project.

http://marionettejs.com/downloads/core/amd/backbone.marionette.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marionette requires backbone so either add marionette to your shim or to your require call,

```
shim:{
  marionette : ['backbone'],
  ...
}
```

or

```
require(['backbone', 'marionette'],function(Backbone, Marionette){
```

Comment: Isn't backbone already defined as a dependency of marionette in the AMD version the OP is using?

Comment: @Jack Indeed. It looks like he is probably using the wrong marionette minified source. As the AMD version doesn't have `Backbone` anywhere in it. Whereas the minified regular version has it right there on line 20.

Comment: I am using the marionette AMD minified source; but it does look like shimming marionette did solve the problem.  Should I be concerned?

Comment: @Bebhead As Jack pointed out, the AMD version should pull it in automatically, I'm highly doubtful that you are using the source you think you are because of the error message you posted.

Comment: @Andrew I double checked.  I AM using the AMD version, and from what I can tell it mentions both Wreqr and Babysitter in there.  However despite that, the only way I have been able to get this to run without any errors is to:
1. Put Backbone.wreqr and Backbone.babysitter in my lib folder with everything else
2. Reference those paths in my require.config paths.

What's interesting is if I do that, I do not seem to need to shim (or at least it gives no immediate errors if I take it off and try to start a marionette app)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Backbone shim might be set up incorrectly. In looking at Marionette's AMD version, it takes a dependency on 'backbone', not 'Backbone'.

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {

  var underscore = require('underscore');
  var backbone = require('backbone');
  var wreqr = require('backbone.wreqr');
  var babysitter = require('backbone.babysitter');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and had spent hours on this issue.
The issue I found after digging into the backbone source code version 1.1.2:

```
(function(root, factory) {

  // Set up Backbone appropriately for the environment. Start with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
      // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
      root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
    });

  // Next for Node.js or CommonJS. jQuery may not be needed as a module.
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    var _ = require('underscore');
    factory(root, exports, _);

  // Finally, as a browser global.
  } else {
    root.Backbone = factory(root, {}, root._, (root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender ||   root.$));
  }

}(this, function(root, Backbone, _, $) {
```

By removing the first two conditions and only leave the third one:

```
root.Backbone = factory(root, {}, root._, (root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender ||   root.$));
```

I was able to make my optimized code with rjs works

Here is my requirejs config

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "/static/src/scripts/js",
  paths: {
    jquery: 'vendors/jquery/jquery',
    underscore: 'vendors/underscore/underscore',
    backbone: 'vendors/backbone/backbone',
    marionette: 'vendors/backbone/backbone.marionette'
  },
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: "jQuery"
    },
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    },
    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    marionette: {
      deps: ['backbone'],
      exports: 'Marionette'
    }
  }
});
```

Hope it helps